What happens if an NTFS file has so many attributes that it exceeds the MFT record size?
I'm messing around with parsing NTFS filesystems. Each file record in the MFT is 1024 bytes long. Attributes for the files are stored in that 1024 bytes, alongside the record header. What happens if you try to store more attributes than will fit? For instance, a heap of $FILE_NAME attributes.
To clarify, while this isn't something I've directly run into yet, I am actually parsing a dd image of an NTFS partition (using NodeJS for convenience - it's surprisingly straightforward) and it's not an exam question. It just occurred to me as a potential issue I might later encounter, and I wasn't able to find anything through Google.

Is this something you are actually experiencing? Is this an exam question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30424102/can-the-ntfs-mft-file-have-child-records

Do the answers in the Stack Overflow question Can a short file uses more MFT records than a longer file? help? They suggest the storage for attributes can exceed the MFT size.

@grawity_u1686 This is the correct answer! Thank you. Unfortunately I can't mark it as a duplicate because it's on SO (which is arguably the wrong site for it).

@Ramhound It's not an exam question lol. I'm parsing a dd image of an NTFS partition for the purposes of learning, for fun and to see whether I can manually fix the corruption (it's from my sister's laptop's NVME drive - it has no critical files but it would be convenient to get a few files back).

For those interested, my jank, half-finished code is now public. It should become much more useful over the next few days.
